# Jackson: Split a json and populate known and unknown properties

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm coding an Spring-boot service and I'm using jackson `ObjectMapper` in order to handle with my jsons.

I need to split a json like this:

```
{
  "copy": {
    "mode": "mode",
    "version": "version"
  },
  "known": "string value",
  "unknown": {
   "field1": "sdf",
   "field2": "sdfdf"
  },
  "unknown2": "sdfdf"
}
```

I mean, my bean is like this:

```
public class MyBean {

    private CopyMetadata copy;
    private String known;
    private Object others;

}
```

I'd like to populate known fields to `MyBean` properties, and move the other unknown properties inside `MyBean.others` property.

Known properties are which are placed as a field inside `MyBean`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove copy and known keys from your object after you have populated the fields in MyBean . Then you can create a hashmap(others) , iterate through the rest properties and get their values .if others need to be an object and the keys and values of the response are dynamical and arbitary then you should store it as a string and encode decode to object when needed. if (others) are static , then create an Object(others) and add them to it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution to this problem is to use the jackson annotations `@JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter`

Your Model Mybean.class should look something like this and it should work

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;

public class MyBean {

    private CopyMetadata copy;
    private String known;
    private Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();

    public CopyMetadata getCopy() {
        return copy;
    }

    public void setCopy(CopyMetadata copy) {
        this.copy = copy;
    }

    public String getKnown() {
        return known;
    }

    public void setKnown(String known) {
        this.known = known;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getOthers() {
        return others;
    }

    public void setOthers(Map<String, Object> others) {
        this.others = others;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getUnknownFields() {
        return others;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setUnknownFields(String name, Object value) {
        others.put(name, value);
    }

}
```